# Updating "left" attribute of a div while hover continueously

Tags: jquery, ajax, hover

i have a question:
i have an inline navigation menu:

```
<nav>
    <div id="highlight"></div>
    <ul id="fs_nav">
         <li class="_nav"><a href="#" title="Home" alt="Home">Home</a></li>
         <li class="_nav second"><a href="#" title="About" alt="About">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="_nav second"><a href="#" title="News" alt="News">News</a></li>
         <li class="_nav second"><a href="#" title="Contacts" alt="Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
         <li class="_nav second"><a href="#" title="Projects" alt="Projects">Projects</a></li>
         <li class="_nav second"><a href="#" title="Donations" alt="Donations">Donations</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

The "highlight" div is an absolute-positioned div that has to highlight the pointed li elements of the navigation moving horizontally.

Now i would like to move it following the mouse position.

I coded this

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
// Highlight Moving
var interval;
    $('nav').hover(function(e){
    interval = setInterval(UpdateX(e),100);
    },
    function(){
        clearInterval(interval);}
       );
    }
);
```

Where UpdateX function is:

```
function UpdateX(e) {
var width = $('#highlight').width();
var left = e.pageX;
$('#highlight').animate({
    left:left - (width/2)
}
);
}
```

But this works just once, when you put the mouse inside "nav". If you want to update the div position you must put out of "nav" the pointer and re-hovering on it.

How can i solve?
Hope to have been clear...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example of this functionality here: http://code.coloresefimeros.com/slide-hover.html

Take a look at the sample code, it will help you with this (JS file involved is http://code.coloresefimeros.com/js/slide-hover.js)

Comment: This is a good solution but i want that the div "following" the mouse in each position and not switching from a li element to the other. My solution works well excepting from be recalled each 100ms. It works just once when you enter the nav. How could i solve that?